# CSS/HTML Inline and center two form buttons of separate forms

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to display two form buttons (each belonging to a separate form) inline and centered (Horizontally).
Here's my code:

```
<div>

<?php
    if(($id && $upperConvLim) || ($id && !$upperConvLim && !$lowerConvLim)){
?>

    <span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" class="previous">
        <input type="submit" value="Previous" name="submit1" />
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$id.'"name = "id" />'; ?>
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$previous.'"name = "previous" />'; ?    >
    </form>

<?php
    }
    if(($id && $lowerConvLim) || ($id && !$upperConvLim && !$lowerConvLim)){
?>

    <span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" class="next">
        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit2" />
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$id.'"name = "id" />'; ?>
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$next.'"name = "next" />'; ?>
    </form>

<?php
    }
?>  

</div>
```

I tried to inline them using the following in my CSS,

```
form, form div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This works fine but I'm unable to center the two buttons. I would like to know both 1) How to center the two buttons as well as 2) If there is a better way to inline them. Appreciate it.

EDIT:  Following Cynthia's suggestion, I changed my php/html code to,

```
<div class="center-form">
<?php
if(($id && $upperConvLim) || ($id && !$upperConvLim && !$lowerConvLim)){
?>
<span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>

<form method="post" action="index.php" class="hform">
        <input type="submit" value="Previous" name="submit1" />
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$id.'"name = "id" />'; ?>
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$previous.'"name = "previous" />'; ?>
</form>

<?php
}

if(($id && $lowerConvLim) || ($id && !$upperConvLim && !$lowerConvLim)){
?>

<span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>

<form method="post" action="index.php" class="hform">
        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit2" />
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$id.'"name = "id" />'; ?>
        <?php echo '<input type = "hidden" value="'.$next.'"name = "next" />'; ?>
</form>


<?php

}

?>
</div>
```

And my new CSS:

```
table {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 10pt
}


#table4 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border:1px solid black;
width :70%;
padding:10px;
background-color:#FAFAD2;
}


#table3 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border:1px solid black;
width :60%;
padding:10px;
background-color:#FFDAB9;
}

/*
form, form div {

  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
*/

.center-form { display:block ; width:165px ; margin:auto }

form.hform { display:inline }

input[type=submit] { padding:4px 0 ; width:80px }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/myQtb/

In a nutshell:

Here is the abbreviated HTML code (I just used barebones forms):

```
<div class="center-form">
<form class="hform">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form class="hform">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset">
</form>
</div>​
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.center-form { display:block ; width:165px ; margin:auto }
form.hform { display:inline }
input[type=submit] { padding:4px 0 ; width:80px }​
```

Why it works:

Change your form tag styling from `inline-block` to simply `inline`. Then enclose BOTH
forms in the `.center-form` DIV that is as wide as the combined width of both buttons.
Assign `display:block` to the `.center-form` DIV and add `margin:auto` (so that the left / right
margins will auto adjust).

And voila!

Comment: I changed the to what you showed but wonder why it's still showing the buttons on separate lines as well as left aligned :(

Comment: It's on my local machine right now. I could put the edited code here..gimme a sec

Comment: Tell you what - can you email me the PHP file and CSS file for that page?

Comment: Get rid of the span tags and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will centre all all elements within a div or form.

```
form, form div {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried that (firefox, chrome) but it doesn't seem to work and also messes up with some of my other layout.